# postgresQL jsonb compare parsing

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have saved data in postgresQL jsonb and I want to compare and parse the jsonb data. For example

I have a table called test

If the column has a column called category and category data,

in the category column

```
{categories:[{"id" : 1}] }
```

in the category data column

```
{categories_data: [{"categories_id": 1}]}
```

If data is stored like this, I want to parse the corresponding object by comparing the id in the category column with the categories_id in the category or data column. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to check if the entries exist in the other column? Or convert the contents of one column to the format of the other? What if one array contains 5 elements and the other only 3? What output do you expect? What if the order of the elements in the array is not the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to compare values from two different jsonb documents. This is how to parse them:

```
SELECT 
  jsonb_array_elements(category->'categories')->'id',
  jsonb_array_elements(categories_data->'categories_data')->'categories_id'
FROM yourtable
```

Demo:

```
WITH j (category,categories_data)AS (
  VALUES ('{"categories":[{"id" : 1}]}'::jsonb,
          '{"categories_data": [{"categories_id": 1}]}'::jsonb)
)
SELECT 
  jsonb_array_elements(category->'categories')->'id'
  =
  jsonb_array_elements(categories_data->'categories_data')->'categories_id'
FROM j;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```